# Open and close expandable button in list view

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a list of Messages that you should be able to click and expand more for info. At the moment, my implementation expands/collapses all messages by clicking on any message.

I tried using the code below:

this.state = {
activeIndex:0,
isExpandable:false
}

And applying the condition as: 
{!this.state.isExpandable && this.state.activeItem === i} to the map() where i was retrieving properties of each object.

[image of buttons in collapsable state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUY98.png)
[image of buttons in expanded state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd7jL.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Card, Feed } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Input } from 'react-input-component';
import { Collapse, Button} from 'reactstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';


function searchingForName(search){
    return function(x){
        return x.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || x.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || !search ;
    }
}

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results:[],
            search:'',
            collapse:false,
            newSearch:'',
            tags:[],
            isExpandable:false,
            activeIndex:0

        }
        this.onchange = this.onchange.bind(this);
        this.toggle  = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.inputKeyDown = this.inputKeyDown.bind(this);
        // this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);

    }
   onchange = e => {
       console.log(this.state.search)
       this.setState({search:e.target.value});
   }

//    handleKeyPress = e => {
//        if(e.key === 'Enter'){
//           this.setState({newSearch: e.target.value});
//        }
//     }

   inputKeyDown = (e) => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    if(e.key === 'Enter' && val){
        if (this.state.tags.find(tag => tag.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase())) {
            return;
          }
        this.setState({tags: [...this.state.tags,val]});
        this.tagInput.value=null;
    }
   }

   toggle(){
       this.setState({collapse: !this.state.collapse});
   }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.students);
            this.setState({results:data.students})
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Card style={{'marginTop':'40px','width':'520px','marginRight':'auto','marginLeft':'auto'}}>
                    <Card.Content>
                    <Input 
                    style={{'width':'519px'}} 
                    placeholder="Search by name..." 
                    onChange={this.onchange} 
                    />
                    <Input 
                    style={{'width':'519px'}} 
                    placeholder="Search by tags..." 
                    onChange={this.onchange} 
                    />
                    {this.state.results.length ? 
                    this.state.results.filter(searchingForName(this.state.search)).map((value,i) => (
                     <Feed>
                       <Feed.Event style={{'margin':'10px'}}>
                       <Image>
                       <Feed.Label image={value.pic} />
                       </Image>
                        <div style={{'float':'right'}}>
                            {!this.state.collapse ? 
                            <Button onClick={this.toggle}>+</Button>
                            : <Button onClick={this.toggle}>-</Button>}
                        </div>
                         <Feed.Content style={{'textAlign':'center','marginBottom':'10px'}}>
                           <Feed.Summary><strong>{value.firstName.toUpperCase()} {value.lastName.toUpperCase()}</strong></Feed.Summary>
                           <Feed.Summary>Email: {value.email}</Feed.Summary>
                           <Feed.Summary>Company: {value.company}</Feed.Summary>
                           <Feed.Summary>Skill: {value.skill}</Feed.Summary>
                           <Feed.Summary>Average : {value.grades.map((x,i,arr)=> {
                                           return x/arr.length;})
                                            .reduce((a,b) => {
                                             return a + b;
                                       }) + "%"}
                           </Feed.Summary><br />
                           <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
                           <Feed.Summary>
                               {Array.isArray(value.grades) && value.grades.map(val => {
                                   return <div>Test {value.grades.indexOf(val)} : {parseFloat(val) + "%"}</div>
                               })}
                           </Feed.Summary><br />
                           {this.state.tags.map((tag,index) => (
                                <div>
                                    <span className="addTag"key={index}>{tag}</span>
                               </div>
                           ))}<br />
                           <input 
                           type="text" 
                           onKeyDown={this.inputKeyDown}
                           ref={c => { this.tagInput = c; }}
                           placeholder="add a tag..."
                           />
                           {/* <div>{this.state.newSearch}</div><br />
                           <Input 
                                style={{'width':'200px'}} 
                                placeholder="add a tag..."  
                                value={this.state.newSearch}
                                onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
                                />  */}
                           </Collapse>
                           <hr/>
                           </Feed.Content>
                           </Feed.Event>
                        </Feed> 
                        )) : ''}
                    </Card.Content>
                    </Card>   
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Image = styled.div`
border: 1px solid #001;
border-radius: 60px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:18px;
height:90px;
width: 90px;
margin-top:30px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-bottom:20px;
`

export default Home;
```

What is causing them all to expand/collapse at once and how can i change that to only expand/collapse the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you don't have isOpened card for every student. You can only open all or none with one single collapse state. I have updated your code with solution here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-kapitsa-tr9yn

I have changes toggle function, which takes index as parameter and updates single students card status - isOpened true or false.

```
  toggle(index) {
    const results = this.state.results.map((item, idx) => {
      if (index === idx) {
        return {
          ...item,
          isOpened: !item.isOpened
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    this.setState({ results });
  }
```

When you load all students data from API endpoint, you have to map through all items and add default isOpened state (by default I've added false - closed).

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.students);
        const results = data.students.map(student => {
          return {
            ...student,
            isOpened: false
          };
        });
        this.setState({ results });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

In render() method I have updated every item to check not this.state.collapse, but student.isOpened on Collapse component and toggle button.

Toggle button

```
<div style={{ float: "right" }}>
  {!value.isOpened ? (
    <Button onClick={() => this.toggle(i)}>+</Button>
  ) : (
    <Button onClick={() => this.toggle(i)}>-</Button>
  )}
</div>
```

Collapse component

```
<Collapse isOpen={value.isOpened}>
  ...
</Collapse>
```

Comment: I got it, thank you so much man, i understood the root cause problem was from ComponentDidMount() itself, not taking each card state independently.

Comment: @TanmayShinde If this answer is helpful, then accept my answer as solution to close the question, by clicking on checkbox.

Comment: actually i also had 1 more doubt, i needed to fill input tags for each card and filter them. I have done filtering for name but i am unable to filter out the tags. Can you help me one more time to filter out the tags. The code is same as before.

Comment: 1. there are no tags in each student object; 2. you should add to state object property for example searchingBy: "name" || "tag" and update your render method if searchingBy === name (the same code) and searchingBy === tag filter by tags.

Comment: Yes i have posted the same question right now, actually i am doing that same from yesterday, but i havent got the results. I tried doing implementation as you did for individual card retrieval.  Tags are to be created own text field onKeyDown event for each card.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131338/open-and-close-all-tags-independently-and-then-filter-those-in-search-filer-box