# Open and close all tags independently and then filter those in search filer box to show the correct card

Tags: html, reactjs

I am facing a uphill task of creating tag in search tag text field within each card and i need to implement is: enter tags in each card differently and later using global search filter for tag to pop up the correct card.

I have tried by binding each card value from array of cards with the tag and tried using filer but unfortunately with my logic i am opening and writing same data to all cards. I am not able to keep different data with each unique card.  Any help would be appreciated!!!.

Needed to implement like this:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4jJV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9apzK.png)

and what i am getting is the below screenshots:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjLZQ.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Card, Feed, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Input } from 'react-input-component';
import { Collapse, Button} from 'reactstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';


function searchingForTag(tag){
    return function(x){
        return x.tag.toLowerCase().includes(tag.toLowerCase()) || !text ;
    }
}

function searchingForName(search){
    return function(x){
        return x.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || x.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || !search ;
    }
}

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results:[],
            search:'',
            collapse:false,
            newSearch:'',
            tags:[]
        }
        this.onchange = this.onchange.bind(this);
        this.toggle  = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.inputKeyDown = this.inputKeyDown.bind(this);
    }
   onchange = e => {
       console.log(this.state.search)
       this.setState({search:e.target.value});
   }


// inputKeyDown = (e) => {
//     const val = e.target.value;
//     if(e.key === 'Enter' && val ){
//         if (this.state.tags.find(tag => tag.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase())) {
//             return;
//           }
//         this.setState({tags: [...this.state.tags,val]});
//         this.tagInput.value=null;
//     }
//    }

inputKeyDown = (e,index) => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    const tags = this.state.tags.map((tag,idx) => {
        if(e.key === 'Enter' && idx === index && val){
            if (this.state.tags.find(tagVal => tagVal.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase())) {
                return;
              }
              return {
                  ...tag
              }
        }
       return tags;
    });
    this.setState({tags:[...this.state.tags,val]});
    this.tagInput.value=null;
}

   toggle(index){
       const results = this.state.results.map((item,idx) => {
           if(index === idx){
               return {
                   ...item,
                   isOpened:!item.isOpened
               };
           }
           return item;
       });
       this.setState({results});
   }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.students);
            const results = data.students.map(student => {
                return {
                    ...student,
                    isOpened:false
                };
            });
            this.setState({results})
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Segment className="body-style">
                <Card style={{'marginTop':'40px','width':'520px','marginRight':'auto','marginLeft':'auto','display':'block'}}>
                    <Card.Content>
                    <Input 
                    style={{'width':'519px'}} 
                    placeholder="Search by name..." 
                    onChange={this.onchange} 
                    />
                    <Input 
                    style={{'width':'519px'}} 
                    placeholder="Search by tags..." 
                    onChange={this.onchange} 
                    />
                    {this.state.results.length ? 
                    this.state.results.filter(searchingForName(this.state.search) || searchingForTag(this.state.tag)).map((value,i) => (
                     <Feed>
                       <Feed.Event style={{'margin':'10px'}}>
                       <Image>
                       <Feed.Label image={value.pic} />
                       </Image>
                        <div style={{'float':'right'}} >
                            {!value.isOpened ?
                            <Button onClick={() => this.toggle(i)}>+</Button>
                            : <Button onClick={() => this.toggle(i)}>-</Button>}
                        </div>
                         <Feed.Content style={{'textAlign':'center','marginBottom':'10px'}}>
                           <Feed.Summary><strong>{value.firstName.toUpperCase()} {value.lastName.toUpperCase()}</strong></Feed.Summary>
                           <Feed.Summary>Email: {value.email}</Feed.Summary>
                           <Feed.Summary>Company: {value.company}</Feed.Summary>
                           <Feed.Summary>Skill: {value.skill}</Feed.Summary>
                           <Feed.Summary>Average : {value.grades.map((x,i,arr)=> {
                                           return x/arr.length;})
                                            .reduce((a,b) => {
                                             return a + b;
                                       }) + "%"}
                           </Feed.Summary><br />
                           <Collapse isOpen={value.isOpened}>
                           <Feed.Summary>
                               {Array.isArray(value.grades) && value.grades.map(val => {
                                   return <div>Test {value.grades.indexOf(val)} : {parseFloat(val) + "%"}</div>
                               })}
                           </Feed.Summary><br />
                           <span>{this.state.tags.map((tag,index) => (
                                <div><span className="addTag" key={index}>{tag}</span></div>
                           ))}</span><br />
                           <input 
                           type="text" 
                           onKeyDown={() => this.inputKeyDown(i)}
                           ref={c => { this.tagInput = c; }}
                           placeholder="add a tag..."
                           />
                           {/* <div>{this.state.newSearch}</div><br />
                           <Input 
                                style={{'width':'200px'}} 
                                placeholder="add a tag..."  
                                value={this.state.newSearch}
                                onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
                                />  */}
                           </Collapse> 
                           <hr/>
                           </Feed.Content>
                           </Feed.Event>
                        </Feed> 
                        )) : ''}
                    </Card.Content>
                    </Card>   
            </Segment>
        )
    }
}

const Image = styled.div`
border: 1px solid #001;
border-radius: 60px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:18px;
height:90px;
width: 90px;
margin-top:30px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-bottom:20px;
`

export default Home;
```

2 tasks to perform here: (1) made different tag for each card, (2) search in global filter with tags to retrieve that card whose tag was filled with that name.

Comment: Your API endpoint should provide student data with tags, adding tags after page has loaded will be no effect, on next page refresh you will loose all your tags edits on the cards. To make them persistent, you have to have support from API endpoint.

Comment: okay got it, so you mean using mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps, bind the state values on the tags to generate the new values. I will try again by implementing that

Comment: you have to persist data in database, mapStateToProps is used in redux for global state managment.

Comment: what i have planned to do is to use redux and using componentWillReceiveProps() which will give new tag to me by calling action creator and then dispatching it through reducers. Lets see what happens but will stick to it.